# @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [com.sample.TestComponent]

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

There are many answers in SO regarding the above question, however my case is different, for me the setters for component is missing.

I have ApplicationComponent which depends on some other component [TestComponent] coming from a library.

```
@AppScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [TestComponent::class],
    modules = [
        AppModule::class,
        AndroidInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    override fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    @ContextIO
    fun getIOCoroutineContext(): CoroutineContext

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun testComponent(testComponent: TestComponent): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

And the application class

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

  val appComponent by lazy {
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .testComponent(SdkInjectors.testComponent())
        .build()
  }
}


@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = {VideoModule.class, AnalyticsModule.class}
)
public interface TestComponent {

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you also share `TestComponent::class` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled upon on some open source project and found this, I was not suppose to use @BindsInstance when creating dependent component.

```
@AppScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [TestComponent::class],
    modules = [
        AppModule::class,
        AndroidInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    override fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    @ContextIO
    fun getIOCoroutineContext(): CoroutineContext

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
      
        fun testComponent(testComponent: TestComponent): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Removing @BindsInstance worked, however I still don't know the reason, will update if I  get to know.